# Duplicate handling on dropped http connections

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api

A client application *creates and moves* resources to a server, i.e. once the client receives an HTTP 200 from the server, it deletes local copies.

The simplified controller action looks like that:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult PostResource(MyModel model)
{
    // creates Id
    await _db.Insert(model);

    return Ok(model);
}
```

Sometimes it happens that the resource is persisted to the database while the client drops the connection (e.g. in China, South East Asia), creating a server side resource but the client doesn't know to delete the local copy and trying again. Sine HTTP is a stateless protocol, neither does the server know the client isn't listening anymore.

What are good strategies to avoid creating duplicates this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some sort of identity on the model. There are a few possible strategies:

1. A simple GUID that the client creates and adds to the model. If it tries to submit a model with the same ID as a previous one that the server already persisted, then it gets an error or something similar. The trick here is how to make sure that the client either generates the same ID all the time or that it persists it somewhere.
2. Some server side generated ID based on the content of the model (this might be expensive) and the client info (IP, name, etc).

Comment: Excellent. Looking into a combination of both because resources can be modified by other users after uploading.

Answer (score 1):

Take the hash ([SHA-256](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256(v=vs.110).aspx) or better) of the resource and use it as a unique key in the database.  Alex Meyer-Gleaves has written about [compute any hash for any object in c#](http://alexmg.com/compute-any-hash-for-any-object-in-c/#)

If the hash already exists, don't do the insert. This makes your POST [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).